# How to push an array to state in React? Getting "Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance"

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to push a movie object into a favorites array in state when something is clicked.

Setting the favoritesArray into state works:

```
addToFavorites = (movie) => {
  const favoritesArray = [];
  favoritesArray.push(movie);
  this.setState({favorites: favoritesArray});
}
```

But when I try to use an updater function as recommended by React I get errors:

```
this.state = {
  favorites: []
};

addToFavorites = (movie) => {
  const favoritesArray = [];
  favoritesArray.push(movie);
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    favorites: [...prevState.favorites, favoritesArray]
  }))
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance

It does seem to work if there's already something in state (not an empty array).

Comment: can tell what is value of prevState.favorites by adding console log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a missmatch in your types, you are adding an array as an element of another array (which I believe is not what you wanted). Also, you can prevent spreading an empty `state.favorites` in the updater function. The following code should work:

```
addToFavorites = (movie) => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        favorites: [...(prevState.favorites || []), movie]
    }));
}
```

The `...(prevState.favorites || [])` makes sure that the spread does not fail in case `prevState.favorites` is `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it gave me the same error. It sort of worked if I flipped it around to [ ] first but then it was only saving 1 movie since it was setting favorites to an empty array first.

This works I think, what do you think?

favorites: [...prevState.favorites.length ? prevState.favorites : [], movie]

Comment: @mikesuchor flipping the `||` is expected to not work. It is strange, that the code I suggested did not work when your new code does. This means that `state.favorites` contains something strange. Can you try to obtain the value of that by doing something like
addToFavorites = (movie) => {
    this.setState(prevState => {
        console.log(prevState.favorites);
        return {
        favorites: [...(prevState.favorites || []), movie]
    }});
}
?

Comment: Thanks for that, that solved the problem. It was giving me an object because I'm running code to sync with firebase in componentDidMount, and forgot the asArray: true property.

Comment: @mikesuchor I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

first of all:
when you tried to spread the old favorites in the new favorites state you forgot to spread the favoritesArray you declared earlier.

The line should have been like this:
favorites: [...prevState.favorites, favoritesArray]

Because you just want to add the movie object to the favorites array you don't even need to declare a favoritesArray. Just add it to the Array in setState. Like this:

```html
addToFavorites = (movie) => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    favorites: [...prevState.favorites, movie]
  }))
}
```

where exactly do you set the state. It seems that your favorites in your prevState are not defined or nothing spreadable like the Error suggests, i.e. not Array, not Object

Comment: Firebase was causing an issue as it was turning the state into an object, I added asArray: true flag and it works now, thanks.